# Adding (Open with ???) in windows context menu

Tags: registry, contextmenu

I use my mouse to High-light text, very often, to search definitions of these words online.
This is usually for my language lessons (Spanish and Italian)

I figure this would be a good way for me to learn how to add a new menu within the Context Menu on my windows 7 machine.

I'd like to High-light a word I read and don't understand "Comida", and right-click on the highlighted text - to see my custom menu "Translate with ....."

By the way, for those of you who are going to tell me to Copy/Paste the text into my browser, just remember I already do that.  I'm simply trying to understand Context Menu Customization, and this seems like a fun way for me to optimize my learning.

I'm reading some decent tutorials on how to modify the registry to allow us to add our own Context Menu options (after right-clicking on something).

One of the most common examples I've seen in tutorials is how to add the CommandPrompt.

This CommandPrompt.reg example simply lets me right-click a folder and open the command prompt into the directory, saving me time.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]
@=”Command Prompt:”
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\Command]
@=”cmd.exe /k cd %1″
```

funny thing, I didn't know windows 7 let's me do the same thing with the Shift key + right-clicking on the folder.

So, I've searched around for modifying the registry, with regards to right-clicking any high-lighted text, and I'm sure my search-terms are not quite getting me there.
This is where I'm seeking a little guidance.

Hopefully my description is clear enough.

Since Text can be practically anywhere on my computer, or in any program (browsers, text docs, folder names, etc.....) I'm definitely in need of some guidance.

Comment: Shell context menus apply only to clicking on files and folders. They do not apply to text.

Comment: alright, thank you for that.  How does the Copy/Paste context menus work then?

Comment: Each application does it its own way. There is no standard for customizing them. You need to do it on app-by-app basis by consulting the documentation for each app.